# Porque no me funciona google acount al generar apk

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, apk

Hice una app con autenticación de google mediante firebase, al ejecutar la app desde Android studio todo me corre perfectamente, al generar la apk y ejecutar desde la misma no me inicia sesión, pueden decirme porque puede ser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando generas el APK y lo firmas con la llave que creaste, debes obtener los datos de esta llave para poder ponerlo en Firebase y que tu app sepa sobre este SHA1

Desde el terminal ubica keytool (se suele ubicar en `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin>`) y debes ingresar el siguiente comando para obtener el SHA1 de produccion

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {nombre_de_la_llave} -alias {alias_keystore}
```

Por ejemplo

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\MG\Desktop\test.jks -alias test
```

una vez que hagas esto se va a mostrar el SHA1 de esta llave, lo copias, vas a Firebase , vas a la configuracion de tu proyecto , agregas un nuevo SHA1 y pones este que acabas de copiar, de esta forma cuando tu app la ejecutes creada para produccion va a poder identificarse con Firebase

Comment: Muchas Gracias, fue de gran ayuda